# Why, when scrolling a page, when scrolling reaches a block with a horizontal block, does it not always scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I just created two blocks, one inside the other. The outer one turned 90 degrees, and the inner one turned 90 degrees back.

There is another way through overflow-x hidden and the jquery mousewhee plugin, but I use smooth scroll in the browser, and the horizontal scroll created in this way will not scroll like the rest of the site.

When I scroll the page and get to the block with a horizontal scroll, I center it in the middle of the monitor screen.
The only problem is that this block does not always scroll horizontally, if you quickly scroll the site with the mouse, this block passes by.

Here is the code:

```
    let horizontalScroll = function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 992) {

            function chk_scroll(e) {
                let elem = $(e.currentTarget);

                if (Math.round(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop()) === elem.outerHeight()) {
                    return true;
                }

            }

            let windowHeight = $(window).height();

            let productsBlockFirst = $('#js-products-block-first');
            let productsBlockMainHeader = $('#js-products-block-first .products-block__main-header');
            let productsBlockFirstHeight = productsBlockFirst.innerHeight() - productsBlockMainHeader.innerHeight();
            let productsBlockFirstOffsetTop = productsBlockFirst.offset().top + productsBlockMainHeader.innerHeight();

            $('.products-block').each(function () {
                let productsBlockOutWrapper = $(this).find('.products-block__outer-wrapper');
                let productsBlockOutWrapperOffsetTop = productsBlockOutWrapper.offset().top;
                let productsBlockOutWrapperScrollTop = productsBlockOutWrapper.scrollTop();
                let productsBlockOutWrapperHeight = productsBlockOutWrapper.innerHeight();
                let productsBlockOutWrapperOffsetBottom = productsBlockOutWrapperOffsetTop + productsBlockOutWrapperHeight;
                let productsBlockOutWrapperScrollHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('products-block__outer-wrapper')[0].scrollHeight;
                let productsBlockWrapperHeight = $('.products-block__wrapper').innerHeight();


                let scrollCenter = productsBlockFirstOffsetTop - ((windowHeight - productsBlockFirstHeight) / 2);

                let iScrollPos = 0;

                let flag = false;

                productsBlockOutWrapper.scroll(function (e) {
                    let currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();


                    if (flag === false) {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: scrollCenter
                        });
                        flag = true;
                    }

                    if (currentScroll === 0) {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: productsBlockOutWrapperOffsetTop - 900
                        });
                        flag = false;
                    } else if (currentScroll > iScrollPos) {
                        if (chk_scroll(e)) {
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: productsBlockOutWrapperOffsetTop + 800
                            });

                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }

                    iScrollPos = currentScroll;
                });
            });
        }

    }
    horizontalScroll();
```

Comment: try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API for this, it was created for problems like yours.

Comment: Thanks, but i need the support for ie.

Comment: then use the polyfill, provided by `w3c` to get it to work in older browsers: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill

Comment: Don't be shy and post a new question so everyone here can help you :)